# zsh compilation problem in OSX

Tags: macos, zsh, osx-lion

I try install zsh

```
git clone git://zsh.git.sf.net/gitroot/zsh/zsh 
cd zsh                                                                                                                            
Util/preconfig  
./configure --prefix=dir
make
```

but, I get this

```
gcc -Wl,-x  -bundle -flat_namespace -undefined suppress -o zleparameter.so   zleparameter..o    -liconv -ldl -ltermcap -lm  -lc
: yodl  -o zsh.texi -I. -w ztexi.yo version.yo zsh.yo; \
        test -f zsh.texi
make[1]: *** [zsh.texi] Error 1
```

Answer (score 4):

Zsh source tarballs are distributed with pre-generated documentation, including the `zsh.texi` file. You checked out zsh from git, so you only get the basic source files. The documentation is generated with [Yodl](http://yodl.sourceforge.net/), and the makefile is set up to build the documentation by default. Install Yodl (on OSX you might need to build it from source). If you're in a hurry and don't want to build the documentation, tweak the toplevel makefile to skip building the documentation: remove `Doc` from `SUBDIRS` and from the `for` loop in the `all` target.

Answer (score -1):

With fully agreement and respect to Gilles I like to add the complete list of commands that I run to successfully install **zsh**.

```
// sudo install build-essential
// sudo install yodl
git clone git://zsh.git.sf.net/gitroot/zsh/zsh
cd zsh
./Util/preconfig
./configure --prefix=/usr/local
make
sudo make install
```

If you run into the error described by JuanPablo run `make clean` before running `make` again.

Comment: apt don't exist in OSX, is question is for OSX